# Login user with DDP.connect() in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to connect two different meteor apps with DDP.connect().
How should I authenticate a user with DDP.connect() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can authenticate this way:

```
var DDPConnection = DDP.connect(<url>);

DDPConnection.call("login", {
                             "password":"qwerty",
                             "user" : {
                                     "email":"email@email.com"
                                 }
                             },
                             function(err,result) {
                                 //Check result
                             }
                  );
```

Check out my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729992/authenticating-with-meteor-via-ddp-and-srp/18645131#18645131) on the different login options depending on the setup you have/want to use.

Comment: Tarang, is the DDP pkg available somewhere? I'd like to extract it out and put it in a chrome extension, so I can do cross-server requests that way.

Comment: Client side JS is a bit tricky because its so tied up to meteor stuff, it might be helpful that way though. Look in the `/packages/livedata` directory of the meteor project on github but you might have to modify it to remove the server side parts