# With Meteor, how to login from remote server?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use 2 servers using DDP.connect.
My subscription works well, but methods called using Meteor.call needs the user to be authenticated.

How can i connect the user to the remote server ?

Comment: what kind of authentication are you using? and who (which software) is taking care of the authentication? are you running behind a proxy? or are you asking about what some of the options for implementing authentication are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can authenticate this way:

```
var DDPConnection = DDP.connect(<url>);

DDPConnection.call("login", {
                             "password":"qwerty",
                             "user" : {
                                     "email":"email@email.com"
                                 }
                             },
                             function(err,result) {
                                 //Check result
                             }
                  );
```

Check out my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729992/authenticating-with-meteor-via-ddp-and-srp/18645131#18645131) on the different login options depending on the setup you have/want to use.