# Meteor - Log user in on the server

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to log a user in from the server side?  I am trying to create a url where an external service/app can login to the meteor server.

I tried doing the following:

```
Meteor.call('login', {
                password: data.password,
                user: {
                    email: data.email
                }
            }, function (error, result) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(result);
            });
```

When called with invalid data such as an email that does not exist or an incorrect password I receive proper error messages like `Incorrect Password`.  But has soon as it is a valid email and password that does exist on the database I receive the following error `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null]`

So what I would like to know is 1) Can I log a user in on the server with this meteor call and 2) Am I doing it properly or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no. The external service would either need to be running meteor client code or it would need to manually make a [DDP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729992/authenticating-with-meteor-via-ddp-and-srp). I suspect you are looking to make a generic-looking HTTP endpoint that any server can connect to. If that's the case, your best bet at the moment is to use something like an API key.

1. Distribute a unique key to each user/customer/service.
2. Require the key in each HTTP request (server-side route).
3. Hope that the keys are not misused/exposed, and program with that possibility in mind.